# MySQL JIRA joining two varchar field

Tags: mysql, sql, jira

[image]See attached image for schema. 
JIRA has two tables that are related to each other through varchar except that one is varchar(60) and the other is varchar(255). I tried the following join and it doesn't work which make sense. So I tried casting both fields (they contain only numbers)... no luck. See my join below:

```
INNER JOIN resolution 
    ON CAST(resolution.id AS unsigned) = CAST(jiraissue.resolution AS unsigned)
```

Also tried:

```
INNER JOIN resolution 
    ON resolution.id = jiraissue.resolution
```

Comment: Can you provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some example data? Also, what is preventing you from changing the data type to INT instead of VARCHAR or at least matching length VARCHAR?

Comment: This should work.  If the foreign key was shorter than the field it was referencing that could be a problem, but the foreign key being longer isn't a problem in MySQL and innoDB.

Comment: Try `ON TRIM(resolution.id) = TRIM(jiraissue.resolution)`